# Rubbish in "GET" response from RallyDev API

Tags: vba, excel, rally

I have an function in Excel:

```
Function getState(Defects As Object) As String

Dim str As String
Dim res As String
Dim was As Boolean
Dim sURL As String
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

was = False

For Each defect In Defects
    If was = False Then
        str = "(FormattedID = """ & defect & """)"
        res = str
        was = True
    Else
        res = res & " OR " & str
    End If
Next defect

sURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?query=(" & res & ")&fetch=FormattedID,State"

oRequest.Open "GET", sURL, True
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
oRequest.Send
oRequest.WaitForResponse
' Set Defects = oRequest.ResponseText
Debug.Print (oRequest.ResponseText)

End Function
```

Unfortunately, i get rubbish instead of json in response like:
?      i?ANA0E?=A(utU
¤RoP°irC°%'.o$%·CI{OOYO????uApeaBRM?Zb?u?OWo?"{oSCy5?(}e??e?qBA"qnu~E·Uu?|?aRbE?a>anµ?c?9P=?A[­Oul?0i  O {PZS?Af~???^??k??R˜?|©?#iEoPNO|?¦'y?vO^Ol? ]?g?#?AjAa?\aC¤y  %©e»]"IHog??@:?· (??"¶E9yog?Az?7bw?/#?eWp^u?ZU?u??3?q?A)cy7µe?E

Could you please take a look at it and provide an solution how it can be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This isn't the problem with the response but it looks like your `For Each` loop just keeps repeating the first defect. You probably need to set the value of `str` before the `If...Else` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larry's answer is correct.

As an aside, if you need to pull data from Rally into Excel, your best bet is the Rally Add-in for Excel:

https://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel

Since you mentioned VBA, you may be working to build some automation in Excel, which the Excel add-in doesn't support. There is an alpha-level Rally Rest Toolkit for VBA. It handles the authentication and REST serialization/de-serialization for you, so it could ease some of your coding effort.

It is unofficial and not supported by Rally, but could be worth trying. Since it is unsupported though, Rally can't help you out if you run into issues. You'd have to refactor your own code against the VBA toolkit to pull the data you want:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/RallyRestToolkitForVBA

Answer (score 1):

The response is compressed. Either try setting a request header for Accept-Encoding: identity or decompress the response.